# Affix a string to items within a lists:flatten in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have a list like this one  `['a','b','c','d']` and what I need is to add a affix to each item in that list like : `['a@erlang','b@erlang','c@erlang','d@erlang']`

I tried using 1lists:foreach1 and then concat two strings to one and then `lists:append` to the main list, but that didn't work for me.

Example of what I tried:

```
LISTa = [],
lists:foreach(fun (Item) ->
    LISTa = lists:append([Item,<<"@erlang">>])
 end,['a','b','c','d'])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be careful, you seems to confuse lists, binaries and atoms. 'a' is an atom. "a" is a list and <<"a">> is a binary. You need conversation to concat them if the data are from different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick (using list comprehensions):

```
1> L = ["a","b","c","d"].
["a","b","c","d"]
2> R = [X ++ "@erlang" || X <- L].
["a@erlang","b@erlang","c@erlang","d@erlang"]
3>
```

Notice that I changed the atoms for strings; It's discouraged to "create atoms on the fly/dynamically" in Erlang, so I have that framed in my mind. If you still need so, change the implementation a little bit and you are good to go.

**NOTE:** I'm assuming the concatenation between atoms and binaries is, somehow, something you did not do on purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the help, works like charm. yes I didn't do it on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
1> L = ['a','b','c','d'].
[a,b,c,d]
2> [ list_to_atom(atom_to_list(X) ++ "@erlang") ||X <- L]. 
[a@erlang,b@erlang,c@erlang,d@erlang]
```

Please try this code, you can use `list_to_atom` and `atom_to_list`.